# Zalenium with Kubernetes in a HUB - Node Model

Tags: kubernetes, zalenium

I am trying to get Zalenium working with kubernetes, and I wanted to understand if Zalenium with kubernetes works in a hub-node architecture, i.e. can I have my Zalenium container running on one node (or the master ) and my selenium containers in other node ? Any help in this direction would be a great help.

Thanks.

I have got my kubectl running and i've created my clusters but I am not able to create separate pods for zalenium and selenium containers and I don't know if they can be even connected.

Answer (score 2):

Right now Zalenium does not have the possibility to decide where the pods get created, so it does that wherever it is deployed and the Zalenium pod interacts with the Kubernetes API to create the docker-selenium pods.
There is a [feature request](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/662) waiting for help to come, so contributions are welomed.
Side note, I think this does not belong to SO, so if you have more questions come to the #zalenium channel in [Slack](https://seleniumhq.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtNTE4MTc4MzYwMjkxLWEyNTZkMDgzNWIwZmY1ZTlmMzg4ZjM1YzZkNGUwZGFlMWE2OTYxMDYxODA1ZWJlMzZjYjc3MmE3ODA1OGZmZTk)